# deploy dynamic routes with nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dynamic, routes, nuxt.js

I am working with Nuxt.js and wanted to deploy my page to Netlify. Everything worked except the dynamic pages I created.

Here is my nuxt.config.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
let dynamicRoutes = () => {
 return axios.get('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/casinos').then(res => {
   return res.data.map(casino => `/casino/${casino.slug}`)
 })
}

export default {
  /*
  ** Nuxt rendering mode
  ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-mode
  */
  mode: 'universal',
  /*
  ** Nuxt target
  ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-target
  */
  target: 'static',
  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-head
  */
  generate: {
    routes: dynamicRoutes
  },
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it like this:

```
generate: {
    routes() {
      return axios.get('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/casinos').then(res => {
        return res.data.map(casino => {
          return {
            route: '/casinos/' + casino.Slug,
            payload: casino
          }
        })
      })
    }
  },
```